# Posting to Google Groups via E-mail - Error if attachments exceed 25MB in total

Tags: google-groups

My understanding with the May 2019 changes the Google Groups posting size was increasing from 8MB to 25MB.  When posting by email I am receiving an 8MB size limit error.  Is there a parameter I need to set to enable this larger message size?